# Is there a library to convert Java POJOs to and from JSON and XML?

Tags: java, xml, json, pojo

I have an object graph that I would like to convert to and from JSON and XML, for the purposes of creating a REST-style API.  It strikes me that someone must have done this already, but a quick search using Google and Stack Overflow reveals nothing.

Does anyone know of a suitable (Apache or equivalent license preferred) library to do this?

Comment: Hy Darren did you have success in your dig about (XML<->JSON).
I'm digging about do it withou POJO, I need to handle with unknown JSON elements and I'm dealing with vectors, hard work, with no solution yet.
Cheers

Comment: XML<->JSON is very problematic, unfortunately, since data models are more different than what one might assume -- basically since XML has no distinction between "objects" and "arrays", unlike JSON

Answer (score 14):

**GSON** from google : http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/,

or

**Jackson** the library used in spring :https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

and I would concur with others suggesting jaxb for XML to pojo, well supported lots of tools : its the standard.

Comment: As an added bonus, Jackson can also do XML, with https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Comment: This is the link on the Jackson page for license info - http://moinmo.in/GPL .  As I understand it - since Jackson has a GPL license, this rules out use of Jackson by any non-opensource software that wants to keep their code confidential.

Answer (score 11):

For POJO to XML I suggest using [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) (there are other libraries as well, such as XStream for example, but JAXB is standardized).

For JSON I don't know anything, but if you want to implement a RESTful API, you might be interested in [JSR-311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) which defines a server-side API for RESTful APIs and [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), which is its reference implementation.

Comment: JAXB may very well be standardized, but it doesn't do collections very well.

Answer (score 6):

Use Xstream http://x-stream.github.io/ for xml and JSON http://www.json.org/java/ for JSON. I dont think there is one library that does both.

Or write a wrapper which delegates to XStream renderers/JSON renderers depending on what you want.

Comment: Xstream supports serialization to JSON: http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html

Comment: I tried Xstream but found a variety of limitations with JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver and the JettisonMappedXmlDriver.
1) The Stream driver cannot deserialize it can only serialize
2) The mapped xml driver can do both but cannot produce pretty JSON
If one is ok with the above constraints, XSTREAM is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be looking for something similar to what is here: [JSON.org Java section](http://www.json.org/java/)

Comment: Did you succeed with this classes? I run some tests and get a infinite loop. I need to parse a generic JSON to XML withou Pojo.

Comment: I actually have since used XStream which seemed to work well.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)** supports mapping a single object model to both XML and JSON with the same metadata:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html

**License Information**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/General#How_is_EclipseLink_Licensed.3F

---

**DOMAIN MODEL**

Below is the domain model we will use for this example.  For this example I'm just using the standard JAXB (JSR-222) annotations which have are available in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6.

***Customer***

```
package forum658936;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    String firstName;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    String lastName;

    @XmlElement(name="phone-number")
    List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

}
```

***PhoneNumber***

```
package forum658936;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PhoneNumber {

    @XmlAttribute
    int id;

    @XmlValue
    String number;

}
```

***jaxb.properties***

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

---

**XML**

***input.xml***

This is the XML that our demo code will read in and convert to domain objects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <firstName>Jane</firstName>
    <lastName xsi:nil="true"/>
    <phone-number id="123">555-1234</phone-number>
</customer>
```

Things to note about the XML:

- The `xsi:nil` attribute is used to indicate that the `lastName` is null.
- The `phone-number` element is a complex type with simple content (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html).

---

**JSON**

***Output***

Below is the JSON that was output by running the demo code.

```
{
   "firstName" : "Jane",
   "lastName" : null,
   "phone-number" : [ {
      "id" : 123,
      "value" : "555-1234"
   } ]
}
```

Things to note about the JSON:

- The `null` value is used to represent that the `lastName` is null.  There is no presence of the `xsi:nil` attribute.
- The collect of phone numbers is of size 1 and is correctly bound by square brackets.  Many libraries incorrectly treat collections of size 1 as JSON objects.
- The `property` of type `int` was correctly marshalled without quotes.
- In the XML representation `id` was an attribute, but in the JSON representation there is not need for it to be specially represented.

---

**DEMO CODE**

In the demo code below we will convert an XML document to objects, and then convert those same instances to JSON.

***Demo***

MOXy doesn't just interpret JAXB annotations it is a JAXB implementation so the standard JAXB runtime APIs are used.  JSON binding is enabled by specifying MOXy specify properties on the `Marshaller`.

```
package forum658936;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum658936/input.xml");
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: this looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

[Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license.

It can also transform JSON objects to XML, but you'd need to convert your POJOs to JSON through it first.

Comment: Does not sound very nice for XML, but looks good for JSON

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would tackle the two separately; and to convert JSON<->XML via JSON<-> Pojo <-> XML.

With that: Java<->POJO with JAXB (http://jaxb.dev.java.net; also bundled with JDK 1.6) with annotations (XStream is ok too); and for JSON, Jackson's ObjectMapper (http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial). Works nicely with Jersey, and I am use it myself (current Jersey version does not bundle full Pojo data binding by default, but will in near future)

I would actually not use any of xml libs to produce "json": XStream and JAXB/Jettison can produce kind of JSON, but it uses ugly conventions that are rather non-intuitive.

EDIT (18-Jul-2011): Jackson actually has an extension called "[jackson-xml-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-xml-databind)" that can read/write XML, similar to JAXB. So it can be used for both JSON and XML, to/from POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

Last I saw on the website, XStream will do both.  It supports XML and JSON as serialization targets.

Answer (score 0):

There are almost literally hundreds. My favorites are GSON for POJO <-> JSON and castor-xml for POJO <-> XML.

As a bonus both are licensed under Apache License 2.0 style licenses.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted.

It is easy to use, performant and was designed with extension in mind.
Actually it does json/java conversion but not xml. However xml support may be added in a future version.

I'm using it in web applications and REST web services in jersey, but also in some cases to store objects in their json form into a database.

Ah and it's under Apache 2.0 license.