# Spring 3 JSON with MVC

Tags: java, web-services, json, spring

Is there a way to build *Spring Web* calls that consume and produce `application/json` formatted requests and responses respectively?

Maybe this isn't *Spring MVC*, I'm not sure.  I'm looking for Spring libraries that behave in a similar fashion to *Jersey/JSON*.  The best case would be if there was an annotation that I could add to the Controller classes that would turn them into *JSON* service calls.

A tutorial showing how to build *Spring Web Services* with JSON would be great.

---

**EDIT:** I'm looking for an annotation based approach (similar to Jersey).

**EDIT2:** Like Jersey, I am looking for REST support (POST,GET,DELETE,PUT).

**EDIT3:** Most preferably, this will be the `pom.xml` entries and some information on using the spring-js with jackson Spring native version of things.

Comment: Similar topic is raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658936/is-there-a-library-to-convert-java-pojos-to-and-from-json-and-xml

Comment: dma_k - that question really isn't that similar.  That question asks about converting between java objects and JSON , this one asks specifically how to use Spring MVC to send and receive JSON messages.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In case other ppl get here later: 
http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/
was the most useful link for me. That finally made me understand the model (after less than a day of searching).

Comment: This is much better if you're already at Spring 3.  The Spring-JSON project is great, but it unfortunately relies on Spring 2.5.

Answer (score 17):

You can certainly have controllers that return a View which is in JSON output. Take a look at [the Spring-JSON project](http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/).

To consume requests in JSON I would assume you would just want a controller to pass a request parameter off to a JSON library which could parse the data?

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want.  It should work like Jersey, I don't want to hand things off, the MVC controller should be wrapped with a JSON aspect layer (probably through annotations) that allows it to send and receive JSON. The Spring-JSON project does half of that (sending) but not the other half.

Answer (score 4):

There is no pre-packaged way to do what you want as Jersey is nicely integrated with Spring via the [Jersey-Spring](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/jersey_and_spring) API so there's really no reason to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I currently use Jersey and it's good.  To be complete honest, I don't find the Spring integration all that compelling, which isn't really a big deal.

Much like Spring MVC versus Struts, I'm not really expecting a lot of change with the Spring Rest JSON functionality, I'm just trying to figure out if it actually exists so I can try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Check this one out

[Adding support for JSON and XML views](http://stsmedia.net/spring-finance-part-7-adding-support-for-json-and-xml-views/)

[Source code for Spring Finance Manager](http://code.google.com/p/spring-finance-manager/)

Comment: These tutorials had references to source code - do you know where the links are to said source code?

Comment: Added the link to the sources

Answer (score 2):

Since spring-mvc 3.0 official support for Ajax remoting with JSON is provided as part of Spring MVC. This includes support for generating JSON responses and binding JSON requests using the Spring MVC @Controller programming model.

see [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now part of Spring since version 3.0. You can simply use the @ResponseBody annotation to specify that you want the return value from your request handler methods to be serialized to JSON and sent as the response body. See http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/server/integration/spring.html) framework looks very close to what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Spring MVC interceptors through [handler mappings](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s04.html) and then use the mappings to transform the returning data to JSON. The handler configuration can be done in xml (no need to recompile), and this can be completely transparent to the rest of the application.

It's fairly easy to annotate controllers with some annotation, and then hook up the BeanFactory bootstrap process to register the controllers within some handler mapping process.

I have used this approach to transform the result from spring controllers into GWT RPC calls.

You can also use Spring AOP to intercept controller method calls and unwrap/wrap the requests from/to JSON.