# In Spring 3.0.5 and coding it to serve JSON, what is this log output trying to tell me?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Using Spring 3.0.5, I am trying to return a list of strings in JSON format.

- I read the post [spring-mvc-json-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203333/spring-mvc-json-response)
- I have available to me jackson-mapper code 1.4.2 and it's on my classpath.
- I am also using `<context:component-scan base-package="com.funfun.foofoo2" />` which should satisfy the  `<mvc:annotation-driven>` requirement.
- I am returning a `List<String>` although I have tried just a bean too.
- When I return raw JSON as a String, it works.

What is the following log output telling me? Is it saying it cannot find the Jackson JSON Mapper and thus the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` is not loaded?

```
17:19:01,037 DEBUG [AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver:132] Resolving exception from handler [com.funfun.foofoo2.CarModelsController@181fa4b]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

17:19:01,037 DEBUG [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:132] Resolving exception from handler [com.funfun.foofoo2.CarModelsController@181fa4b]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

17:19:01,037 DEBUG [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:132] Resolving exception from handler [com.funfun.foofoo2.CarModelsController@181fa4b]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
17:19:01,053 DEBUG [DispatcherServlet:824] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

*Update:* I am using jQuery's getJSON.  In Firefox Firebug, I see the header coming over as application/json.  The Spring method is constrained to only handle requests for JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than `jackson-mapper`, you need `jackson-core` as well, and preferably something newer than the rather old 1.4.x versions.

Comment: Hopefully, the ivy system is handling that correctly in our repo. I will check. Thanks!

Comment: I added jackson, jackson-core-asl, jackson-mapper, jackson-mapper-asl (1.4.2, 1.5.5, 1.4.2, 1.5.5 respectively). Same result.

Comment: Another project is using slightly newer stuff and it is rumored to be working. Thanks for your suggestion about the libraries. Do I need jackson-mapper-asl (and its core)?

Comment: @finneycanhelp: `-asl` means "Apache Source Licence". Jackson is available under 2 different licences. You only need one set.

Comment: @finneycanhelp you need mapper and core for sure; spring probably does not need more (jax-rs containers could use jackson-jaxrs) too. But problem does not sound so much a Jackson problem than issue with content-type (i.e. request is specifying it wants something other than JSON?)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! :)  The request is a JSON request for sure. The sender is using a getJSON call and the receiver (controller) has specified that it will only accept JSON GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what this exception (`HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`) means is that the client is specifying an `accepts` header in their HTTP request, and it likely isn't accepting JSON. How are you making this request? AJAX call? If so, use Firebug or something to inspect the XHR and see what the accepts header is set to.

Comment: Thank you. I will add more to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the Accept param in your HTTP request header. If you are using XMLHttpRequest to make the ajax call, don't forget to change the requestHeader as follow:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", custom_url, this.async);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
```

Regards,

David.