# integrating jqgrid, mybatis, spring mvc and postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, jqgrid, mybatis

How can i integrate  jqgrid, mybatis, spring mvc and postgresql when i have to display data using jqgrid/JSP via Json.

The project needs to display data from various table in single JSP page as well there must be pagination included.

I searched all over but didn't find a single working tutorial.
Only at krams i found a tutorial but it takes static data.
while i need to display data from a DB in postgres which will be managed via mybatis-spring mvc.

the table should look like this

[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22sAL.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you'll be able to find working tutorials that integrate all the technologies in your stack.

1. Here is the [Mybatis Spring Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Spring).
2. Here is a question on Spring MVC Json Response.  [Spring MVC -> JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203333/spring-mvc-json-response)
3. Here is [jqGrid examples](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data).

Start slow, don't try to put it together all at once.  First write a simple service using MyBatis to select some data objects.  Then do the Spring MVC part to return json.  Then integrate into the jqGrid.

Jackson is a great Json library, it's very fast.

I would suggest writing unit tests after each step.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Pryor, I guess thats the way to go..!! :)

Comment: @Nomad  No problem,  welcome to stackoverflow.  I suggest accepting answers if they solve your problem.  In the future, it makes more people more likely to answer your qiestions.  You can read more in the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq