# spring mvc using json instead of ${variable}

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

Basically, I've currently got an MVC project I'm working on where I can pass values from the server to the client using the following class...

```
package org.assessme.com;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class UserManagementController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userManagement", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("User management view controller loaded...");

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        return "userManagement";
    }
}
```

This can then be accessed using the notation...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, how would I change this project so that I could use JSON as the Ajax requests so say a user clicks a button that has...

```
function userManage(){
    $('div.mainBody').load('userManagement');
}
```

I want userManagement to return the view userManagement (like it does now), but also a json response of users.

Can anyone give me any advice around this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/), the author explains how you can achieve this using Spring.

In your controller, you should have something like the below to return a JSON.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/availability", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody AvailabilityStatus getAvailability(@RequestParam String name) {
    for (Account a : accounts.values()) {
        if (a.getName().equals(name)) {
            return AvailabilityStatus.notAvailable(name);
        }
    }
    return AvailabilityStatus.available();
}
```

In your view, you should write a request using JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check name availability on focus lost
    $('#name').blur(function() {
        checkAvailability();
    });
});

function checkAvailability() {
    $.getJSON("account/availability", { name: $('#name').val() }, function(availability) {
        if (availability.available) {
            fieldValidated("name", { valid : true });
        } else {
            fieldValidated("name", { valid : false,
                message : $('#name').val() + " is not available, try " + availability.suggestions });
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: You should also check [this answear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4204825/1334930). If you add Jackson jars to your libs, Spring will start to parse your POJOS to JSON.

Comment: From what I can see though, this only returns the JSON value, not the view I want the page to be routed to.  Is it possible to do both at the same time?

Comment: thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/06/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc.html :) thank you