# Spring dojo request issue

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, dojo

I am quite new to Spring framework and i have a problem.
I have a page A.jsp and in this page i have a link to page B.jsp

```
<c:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" var="contextPath" />
Click <a href="${contextPath}/pageB">here</a>
```

And in controller

```
@RequestMapping("pageB")
public String pageBlink(SitePreference sitePreference, Device device, Model model) {
return "pageB";     
}
```

Now on page B.jsp i want to invoke an Ajax call.

```
I have a link <a href="javascript:myFunction();">Send request</a>

function myFunction(){
dojo.xhrGet({
// The URL of the request
url: "requestPage",
method: "POST",
handleAs: "json",
// The success callback with result from server
load: function(jsonData) {
var content = "";
                                dojo.forEach(jsonData.newsItems,function(locationPoint) {
// Build data from the JSON
content += "<p>" + locationPoint.name + "</p>";
content += "<p>" + locationPoint.latitude + "</p>";
content += "<p>" + locationPoint.longitude + "</p>";
content += "<p>" + locationPoint.number + "</p>";
});
},
// The error handler
error: function() {
// Do nothing -- keep old content there
},
// generate an extra GET variable to prevent browsers from caching
preventCache: true
});
}
```

And add into controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="requestPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public MyObj returnEVSELocations(){
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "return evse locations --------------");
    MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    // add some stuff into the obj

    return myObj;
}
```

But this request a requestPage.jps ... i want just to work in my page (B.jsp).
Any help is more than welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence which contains the problem and what it should be, so it's pretty hard to give an answer. Could you provide more information?

Comment: I mean that in the console the error message says that there is no requestPage.jsp page found. I want to retrieve the response in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
In fact there was 2 problems
1. In Ajax call i must have
`dojo.forEach(jsonData, ...)` instead `dojo.forEach(jsonData.newsItems, ...)`
2. In the controller in on my method i must add the annotation

```
public @ResponseBody MyObj
```

I hope this help someone to front the same issue.

Comment: You could have found the answer here I guess : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203333/spring-mvc-json-response