# Spring-mvc and Ajax jquery : can't have a response from the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

In my client, I send a request using ajax to a Spring controller. This last can intercept it, but when I return a value, I can't can't have it in my client side.

Client code :

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           data: {name : "name"},
           url: "/web/private/frontend/accueil/dateHistorique.html",
           success: function(msg){
                alert("Hello");
           }
        });
```

Server side code :

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/dateHistorique.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> getAllowedDate(@RequestParam String name) {
    System.out.println("***********************************" + name);
    AllowedDates allowedDates = new AllowedDates("1","20");
    Map<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    responseMap.put("Name", "Marouane");
    return responseMap;
}
```

I can see the out put in the server : ****************name but always don't have a response.
Thnx

Comment: '/web/private/frontend/accueil/dateHistorique.html' is looking like a filesystem path. sure you can call it via a browser?

Comment: It's just a mapping :) it's working now, I just need to return an object, that can be transformed to JSON. how to do ?

Comment: don't know spring but found this: http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/ (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601992/spring-3-json-with-mvc)

Comment: Use firebug in your browser so you can se more information about the request. In the tab Net you'll see the requests and the responses. Can you tell us the status code of the response is 200 and if the response content is what you are expecting?

Comment: I didn't add <mvc:annotation-driven /> Thnx all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should add `Jackson` to my pom and `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to my mvc-servlet-context