# Library to encode/decode from json to java.util.Map?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, converters

Does anyone knows a java library that could easily encode java Maps into json objects and the other way around?

**UPDATE**

For reasons couldn't explain  ( and I hate sometimes ) I can't use generics on my environment.

What' I'm trying to do is to have something like this:

```
Map a = new HashMap();
a.put( "name", "Oscar" );

Map b = new HashMap();
b.put( "name", "MyBoss"); 
a.put( "boss",  b ) ;


List list = new ArrayList();
list.add( a );
list.add( b );


 String json = toJson( list );
 // and create the json:
 /*
    [
       {
         "name":"Oscar",
         "boss":{
              "name":"MyBoss"
         }
        },
        {
            "name":"MyBoss"
        }
     ]

  */
```

And be able to have it again as a list of maps

```
 List aList = ( List ) fromJson( jsonStirng );
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658936/is-there-a-library-to-convert-java-pojos-to-and-from-json-and-xml

Comment: @dma_k Thanks for the reference. I actually neede something like the last one because I didn't meant to bind to a bean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[JSON-Simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) looks relatively easy to use (examples below).

Map to JSON:

```
  Map map = new HashMap();
  map.put("name", "foo");
  map.put("nickname", "bar");
  String jsonText = JSONValue.toJSONString(map);
```

JSON to List/Map:

```
  String s = yourJsonString;
  List list = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(s);       
  Map map = (JSONObject) list.get(0);
```

Comment: This one did the work. I like Gson better for bean binding but unfortunately in my environment I can't use generics on which Gson relies heavily.  JSON-Simple have a little bug though which I think could be easily solved:  http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/issues/detail?id=18  I'm using this anyway, thanks for the link

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think you have to use generics even with GSON -- I am pretty sure it, too, would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot after hours of searching i got an answer

Answer (score 33):

You can use [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for that. It has excellent support for [Generic types](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener).

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2496494;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String... args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        map.put("key3", "value3");
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // Serialize.
        String json = gson.toJson(map);
        System.out.println(json); // {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}

        // Deserialize.
        Map<String, String> map2 = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType());
        System.out.println(map2); // {key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to decode ( deserialize ) to non generic map ?

Comment: Either replace `Map<String, String>` by `Map<String, Object>` or `Map<Object, Object>`. Or, more OO-friendly, just use a fullworthy Javabean. Gson can handle it perfectly as well. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182

Comment: The problem is I'm using an environment that doesn't support generics,  ( erhmm. don't ask me how or why, I just, can't use them ) and what I'm trying to find is a way to convert  plain lists of maps to json and have them back.

Comment: I see. Does it run Java 1.5 at any way? Else Gson won't run at any way. You may consider to have a look at Jackson then: http://jackson.codehaus.org/ (tutorial here http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial, `Ctrl+F` on "untyped" to achieve the same what you want). The reason I suggest Jackson is by the way because it is **fast**. Benchmarks here BTW: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/02/entry_204.html

Comment: Awesome answer. I've totally missed the TypeToken class, and could't remember what I did wrong. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can view the site from [Json.org](http://www.json.org/) for the list of good JSON libraries in Java.

JSon.org's own [implementation](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) `JSONObject` can do just that.
From their JavaDoC

```
 /**
     * Construct a JSONObject from a Map.
     * 
     * @param map A map object that can be used to initialize the contents of
     *  the JSONObject.
     */
    public JSONObject(Map map);
```

you can do

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(map);
```

To convert JSON String back to object....

```
String jsonString = "{\"name\" : \"some name\", \"age\" : 10}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

and you can access values like:

```
int age = json.getInt("age");
```

Constructor JavaDoC

> Construct a JSONObject from a source
>   JSON text string. This is the most
>   commonly used JSONObject constructor.
>
> Parameters: source A string beginning
>   with `{` (left brace) and ending with `}`
>   (right brace).

Comment: This goes from Map -> JSONObject, but the questioner wants both directions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the real question would be which JSON library (from org.json's page) would NOT allow doing this. As far as I know every single library there would allow this in some form.
So every library mentioned so far works.

And to add some information, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) works very well with all kinds of data including basic Maps and Lists:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValue(list);
List listOfMaps = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);
```

which would handle this particular case. While generic type information can be used, it is optional when using "natural" binding to JDK container types.

Answer (score 1):

We use http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ in our project, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When using google gson.

```
var getRowData =
[{
    "dayOfWeek": "Sun",
    "date": "11-Mar-2012",
    "los": "1",
    "specialEvent": "",
    "lrv": "0"
},
{
    "dayOfWeek": "Mon",
    "date": "",
    "los": "2",
    "specialEvent": "",
    "lrv": "0.16"
}];

    JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(request.getParameter("getRowData"));
     JsonArray  jsonArray = root.getAsJsonArray();
     JsonObject  jsonObject1 = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
     String dayOfWeek = jsonObject1.get("dayOfWeek").toString();
```

// when using jackson

```
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(getRowData);
          // advance stream to START_ARRAY first:
          jp.nextToken();
          // and then each time, advance to opening START_OBJECT
         while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            Map<String,Object> userData = mapper.readValue(jp, Map.class);
            userData.get("dayOfWeek");
            // process
           // after binding, stream points to closing END_OBJECT
        }
```

Comment: If you think the same exact answer applies to more than one question, maybe they're duplicate and should be flagged as such, don't you think ?