# Deserialize a List<T> object with Gson?

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I want to transfer a list object via Google Gson, but I don't know how to deserialize generic types.

What I tried after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496494/library-to-encode-decode-from-json-to-java-util-map) (BalusC's answer):

```
MyClass mc = new Gson().fromJson(result, new List<MyClass>() {}.getClass());
```

but then I get an error in Eclipse saying "The type new `List<MyClass>() {}` must implement the inherited abstract method..." and if I use a quick fix I get a monster of over 20 method stubs.

I am pretty sure that there is an easier solution, but I seem unable to find it!

Now I have this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>() {}.getType();

MyClass mc = new Gson().fromJson(result, listType);
```

However, I do get the following exception at the `fromJson` line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.length(ListOfTypes.java:47)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.toString(ImplForType.java:83)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:203)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:56)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:88)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:76)
at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:106)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonArray(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:64)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:49)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:568)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:515)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:484)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:434)
```

I *do* catch `JsonParseExceptions` and `result` is not null.

I checked `listType` with the debugger and got the following:

- `list Type`

  - `args = ListOfTypes`

    - `list = null`
    - `resolvedTypes = Type[ 1 ]`
  - `loader = PathClassLoader`
  - `ownerType0 = null`
  - `ownerTypeRes = null`
  - `rawType = Class (java.util.ArrayList)`
  - `rawTypeName = "java.util.ArrayList"`

So it seems the `getClass` invocation didn't work properly. Any suggestions...?

I've checked on the [Gson User Guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener). It mentions a runtime exception that should happen during parsing a generic type to Json. I did it "wrong" (not shown above), just as in the example, but didn't get that exception at all. So I changed the serialization as in the user guide suggested. Didn't help, though.

Edit:

Solved, see my answer below.

Comment: The answer you pointed to, uses `TokenType`. Have you tried that way?

Comment: just got the same hint as an answer. next time I'll give the example a closer look. ;)

Comment: Can you try an implementation of list in type token? Since your raw type is array list you should try array list.

Answer (score 1112, accepted):

Method to deserialize generic collection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

...

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>(){}.getType();
List<YourClass> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Since several people in the comments have mentioned it, here's an explanation of how the `TypeToken` class is being used. The construction `new TypeToken<...>() {}.getType()` captures a compile-time type (between the `<` and `>`) into a runtime `java.lang.reflect.Type` object. Unlike a `Class` object, which can only represent a raw (erased) type, the `Type` object can represent any type in the Java language, including a parameterized instantiation of a generic type.

The `TypeToken` class itself does not have a public constructor, because you're not supposed to construct it directly. Instead, you always construct an anonymous subclass (hence the `{}`, which is a necessary part of this expression).

Due to type erasure, the `TypeToken` class is only able to capture types that are fully known at compile time. (That is, you can't do `new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType()` for a type parameter `T`.)

For more information, see the [documentation for the `TypeToken` class](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html).

Comment: In new versions of GSON the TypeToken contructor is not public, hence here you get constructor not visible error. What do you have to do in this case?

Comment: Using actual version of GSON (2.2.4) it works again. You can access the constructor here.

Comment: my json object starts with an object, then contains an array of the object I want  `{ "myObjectArray":[ {....} , {....} , {....} ] }`, I have made the model file for `{....}` , how do I get this generic collection code to not assume my root element is an array without making a new nested object file

Comment: Check the link to have another way to write a better util class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139437/java-type-generic-as-argument-for-gson

Comment: which package is neede for the type.getType() instruction? I am getting "The method getType() is undefined for the type new ArrayList<XXXX>(){}"

Comment: It gives me error if i use proguard only otherwise its work. any suggestion

Comment: Following Imports required ---   

import java.lang.reflect.Type;    
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

Comment: This is good if YourClass is fixed in code. What if the class comes at runtime?

Comment: then you will most likely run into a class cast exception (java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap) when you try to use it

Comment: Those `{}` before `.getType` look so non-Java to me. I'm not even able to tell what they are syntacically. Is it an empty anonymous class or what?

Comment: @CQM You have two ways.1-Just remove the first and the last character from the string and you're good to go.2-Make a Class put your ArrayList<Whatever> in that class,Now just use Whatever.class,For the second argument you're good to go.

Comment: for kotlin `val listType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>() {}.type`

Comment: @jasxir, if the type argument is dynamic and not known at compile time, use `TypeToken.getParameterized`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51943312).

Answer (score 309):

Another way is to use an array as a type, e.g.:

```
MyClass[] mcArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass[].class);
```

This way you avoid all the hassle with the Type object, and if you really need a list you can always convert the array to a list by:

```
List<MyClass> mcList = Arrays.asList(mcArray);
```

IMHO this is much more readable.

And to make it be an actual list (that can be modified, see limitations of `Arrays.asList()`) then just do the following:

```
List<MyClass> mcList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mcArray));
```

Comment: this is great! How can I use it with reflection?
I dont know the `MyClass` value and it will be defined dynamically!

Comment: nota: with this, be careful that mcList is not a full-fledged list. many things will not work.

Comment: How to use it with generics? `T[] yourClassList = gson.fromJson(message, T[].class);` //cannot select from type variable

Comment: @njzk2 What exactly is a full-fledged list?

Comment: @MateusViccari at the time of that comment, `mcList` in this answer was only the result of the call to `Arrays.asList`. This method returns a list on which most if not all optional methods are left unimplemented and throw exceptions. For instance, you cannot add any element to that list. As the later edit suggests, `Arrays.asList` has limitations, and wrapping it into an actual `ArrayList` allows you to get a list that is more useful in many cases.

Comment: dont forget before Gson gson = new Gson(); for begineers

Comment: If you need to construct an array type at runtime for an arbitrary element type, you can use `Array.newInstance(clazz, 0).getClass()` as described in [David Wood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type/36338377#36338377).

Answer (score 90):

Since Gson 2.8, we can create util function like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getList(String jsonArray, Class<T> clazz) {
    Type typeOfT = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, clazz).getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, typeOfT);
}
```

Example usage:

```
String jsonArray = ...
List<User> user = getList(jsonArray, User.class);
```

Comment: `TypeToken#getParameterized` looks a way better then the hack with an anonymous subclass

Comment: I copied your method "as is" and it does not work : compiler says "The method getParameterized(Class<List>, Class<T>) is undefined for the type TypeToken". I checked both my Gson version (2.8.0) and documentation and everything is fine on this side... I ended up using @Happier solution which works fine

Comment: @leguminator did you import TypeToken correct? and you are using java or kotlin. I will try to test again

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Absolutely : I am using Java and imported "com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken" and "java.lang.reflect.Type". I doubled check method implementation : it is declared as "public static TypeToken<?> getParameterized(Type rawType, Type... typeArguments)"

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, simple, it uses the Gson API, and there are no hacks around it. +1

Comment: For what it's worth the solution using an anonymous `TypeToken` subclass is not really a hack, but the officially recommended usage by Gson (see its Javadoc and the [User Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)). The main advantage is that it makes sure you construct proper parameterized types. `TypeToken.getParameterized` cannot perform any validation at compile time so you could construct types such as `List<String, String, String>` or `Map<Integer>`; the latest Gson versions at least detect these bad types at runtime.

Comment: @Marcono1234 Another advantage of anonymous TypeToken is shown when we need nested generics. For instance while parsing `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` I would rather read/maintain code with `new TypeToken<List<List<Integer>>(){}.getType()` than `TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, Integer.class).getType()).getType()`.

Answer (score 32):

Refer to this post.
[Java Type Generic as Argument for GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139437/java-type-generic-as-argument-for-gson)

I have better solution for this. Here's the wrapper class for list so the wrapper can store the exactly type of list.

```
public class ListOfJson<T> implements ParameterizedType
{
  private Class<?> wrapped;

  public ListOfJson(Class<T> wrapper)
  {
    this.wrapped = wrapper;
  }

  @Override
  public Type[] getActualTypeArguments()
  {
      return new Type[] { wrapped };
  }

  @Override
  public Type getRawType()
  {
    return List.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Type getOwnerType()
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And then, the code can be simple:

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(String json, Class<T> typeClass)
{
    return sGson.fromJson(json, new ListOfJson<T>(typeClass));
}
```

Comment: What is `mEntity.rulePattern`?

Comment: It's just a sample object for test. You don't need to care about it. Use toList method and everything goes well.

Answer (score 29):

Wep, another way to achieve the same result. We use it for its readability.

Instead of doing this hard-to-read sentence:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>(){}.getType();
List<YourClass> list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Create a empty class that extends a List of your object:

```
public class YourClassList extends ArrayList<YourClass> {}
```

And use it when parsing the JSON:

```
List<YourClass> list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, YourClassList.class);
```

Answer (score 14):

For Kotlin simply:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
...
val type = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
```

or, here is a useful function:

```
fun <T> typeOfList(): Type {
    return object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
}
```

Then, to use:

```
val type = typeOfList<YourMagicObject>()
```

Comment: I've used your code to create this function using reified types:
`inline fun <reified T> buildType() = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type!!`
and call it with the List type: `buildType<List<YourMagicObject>>()`

Comment: @coffeemakr You don't need reified types here.

Comment: Oh. But why do you create the type token of a ArrayList in `buildType` and also call the function with the generic type? Is this a typo? - This would create ArrayList<ArrayList<YourMagicObject>>

Comment: @coffeemakr ah, yeah. Typo

Answer (score 7):

```
public static final <T> List<T> getList(final Class<T[]> clazz, final String json)
{
    final T[] jsonToObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz);

    return Arrays.asList(jsonToObject);
}
```

Example:

```
getList(MyClass[].class, "[{...}]");
```

Comment: Good one. But this duplicates `DevNG`s above answer, written 2 years earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17300003/1339923 (and read that answer for caveats to this approach)

Answer (score 6):

As it answers my original question, I have accepted doc_180's answer, but if someone runs into this problem again, I will answer the 2nd half of my question as well:

The NullPointerError I described had nothing to do with the List itself, but with its content!

The "MyClass" class didn't have a "no args" constructor, and neither had its superclass one. Once I added a simple "MyClass()" constructor to MyClass and its superclass, everything worked fine, including the List serialization and deserialization as suggested by doc_180.

Comment: If you have a list of abstract classes you'll get the same error. I guess this is GSON's general error message for "Unable to instantiate class".

Comment: The tip about adding a constructor helped me realize why I had all null-values. I had field names like "To" and "From" in my JSON-string, but the corresponding fields in my object were "to" and "from" in lower case, so they were skipped

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that works with a dynamically defined type.  The trick is creating the proper type of of array using `Array.newInstance()`.

```
public static <T> List<T> fromJsonList(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    Object [] array = (Object[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, 0);
    array = gson.fromJson(json, array.getClass());
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++)
        list.add(clazz.cast(array[i]));
    return list; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to add for one more possibility. If you don't want to use TypeToken and want to convert json objects array to an ArrayList, then you can proceed like this:

If your json structure is like:

```
{

"results": [
    {
        "a": 100,
        "b": "value1",
        "c": true
    },
    {
        "a": 200,
        "b": "value2",
        "c": false
    },
    {
        "a": 300,
        "b": "value3",
        "c": true
    }
]
```

}

and your class structure is like:

```
public class ClassName implements Parcelable {

    public ArrayList<InnerClassName> results = new ArrayList<InnerClassName>();
    public static class InnerClassName {
        int a;
        String b;
        boolean c;      
    }
}
```

then you can parse it like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
final ClassName className = gson.fromJson(data, ClassName.class);
int currentTotal = className.results.size();
```

Now you can access each element of className object.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to example 2 for 'Type' class understanding of Gson.

Example 1: In this deserilizeResturant we used Employee[] array and get the details

```
public static void deserializeResturant(){

       String empList ="[{\"name\":\"Ram\",\"empId\":1},{\"name\":\"Surya\",\"empId\":2},{\"name\":\"Prasants\",\"empId\":3}]";
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       Employee[] emp = gson.fromJson(empList, Employee[].class);
       int numberOfElementInJson = emp.length();
       System.out.println("Total JSON Elements" + numberOfElementInJson);
       for(Employee e: emp){
           System.out.println(e.getName());
           System.out.println(e.getEmpId());
       }
   }
```

Example 2:

```
//Above deserilizeResturant used Employee[] array but what if we need to use List<Employee>
public static void deserializeResturantUsingList(){

    String empList ="[{\"name\":\"Ram\",\"empId\":1},{\"name\":\"Surya\",\"empId\":2},{\"name\":\"Prasants\",\"empId\":3}]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // Additionally we need to se the Type then only it accepts List<Employee> which we sent here empTypeList
    Type empTypeList = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Employee>>(){}.getType();


    List<Employee> emp = gson.fromJson(empList, empTypeList);
    int numberOfElementInJson = emp.size();
    System.out.println("Total JSON Elements" + numberOfElementInJson);
    for(Employee e: emp){
        System.out.println(e.getName());
        System.out.println(e.getEmpId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using Kotlin, you can get generic MutableList type for all custom Serializable  Types

```
private fun <T : Serializable> getGenericList(
    sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
    key: String,
    clazz: KClass<T>
): List<T> {
    return sharedPreferences.let { prefs ->
        val data = prefs.getString(key, null)
        val type: Type = TypeToken.getParameterized(MutableList::class.java, clazz.java).type
        gson.fromJson(data, type) as MutableList<T>
    }
}
```

you can call this function

```
getGenericList.(sharedPrefObj, sharedpref_key, GenericClass::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case @uncaught_exceptions's answer didn't work, I had to use `List.class` instead of `java.lang.reflect.Type`:

```
String jsonDuplicatedItems = request.getSession().getAttribute("jsonDuplicatedItems").toString();
List<Map.Entry<Product, Integer>> entries = gson.fromJson(jsonDuplicatedItems, List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created [GsonUtils](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/GsonUtils) lib for this case. I add this into maven central repository.

```java
Map<String, SimpleStructure> expected = new HashMap<>();
expected.put("foo", new SimpleStructure("peperoni"));

String json = GsonUtils.writeValue(expected);

Map<String, SimpleStructure> actual = GsonUtils.readMap(json, String.class, SimpleStructure.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

I liked the answer from kays1 but I couldn't implement it. So I built my own version using his concept.

```
public class JsonListHelper{
    public static final <T> List<T> getList(String json) throws Exception {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
        Type typeOfList = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, typeOfList);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<MyClass> MyList= JsonListHelper.getList(jsonArrayString);
```

Comment: Surely this cannot work since you're trying to use T in compile-time. This will effectively deserialize to a List of StringMap, no?