# Using GSON to parse a JSON array

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I have a JSON file like this:

```
[
    {
        "number": "3",
        "title": "hello_world",
    }, {
        "number": "2",
        "title": "hello_world",
    }
]
```

Before when files had a root element I would use:

```
Wrapper w = gson.fromJson(JSONSTRING, Wrapper.class);
```

code but I can't think how to code the `Wrapper` class as the root element is an array.

I have tried using:

```
Wrapper[] wrapper = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Wrapper[].class);
```

with:

```
public class Wrapper{

    String number;
    String title;

}
```

But haven't had any luck. How else can I read this using this method?

P.S I have got this to work using:

```
JsonArray entries = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
String title = ((JsonObject)entries.get(0)).get("title");
```

But I would prefer to know how to do it (if possible) with both methods.

Comment: Are you sure there is comma after title elements? If you remove them `Wrapper[] data = gson.fromJson(jElement, Wrapper[].class);` works fine for me.

Comment: That'l be the problem.. such a simple mistake!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Problem is caused by comma at the end of (in your case *each*) JSON object placed in the array:

```
{
    "number": "...",
    "title": ".." ,  //<- see that comma?
}
```

If you remove them your data will become

```
[
    {
        "number": "3",
        "title": "hello_world"
    }, {
        "number": "2",
        "title": "hello_world"
    }
]
```

and

```
Wrapper[] data = gson.fromJson(jElement, Wrapper[].class);
```

should work fine.

Comment: @Snake take a look at [Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554217)

Comment: @Snake BTW, in case of `jackson` library and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects#comment37099398_6349488) creating array and wrapping it with `Arrays.asList(..)` is faster than creating a list using TypeRefence. I didn't test it with `gson` library but it may be worth to benchmark it.

Answer (score 42):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Wrapper[] arr = gson.fromJson(str, Wrapper[].class);

class Wrapper{
    int number;
    String title;       
}
```

Seems to work fine. But there is an extra `,` Comma in your string.

```
[
    { 
        "number" : "3",
        "title" : "hello_world"
    },
    { 
        "number" : "2",
        "title" : "hello_world"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 17):

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (null == json) {
        return null;
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType());
}
```

sample call:

```
List<Specifications> objects = GsonUtils.toList(products, Specifications.class);
```

Comment: For me, this is turning my objects into a List of LinkedTreeMap instead of a List of Specification objects(for example).

Comment: Where did you get GsonUtils class?

Comment: ``GsonUtils`` is the class where he put his own ``toList()`` method.

Comment: This cannot work: the TypeToken must create a wrong value since T isn't known when this is compiled. That'll probably create the type token for List<Object>. You'd have to use the actual class when creating the type.

Answer (score 2):

```
Wrapper[] data = gson.fromJson(jElement, Wrapper[].class);
```