# Parsing JSON data into a Class

Tags: java, json, gson

**Class:**

```
public class MyList {

    public int type;
    public String text;
    public boolean[] arr;

    public MyList(int type, String text) {
        this.type = type;
        this.text = text;
        switch (type) {
        case 0:
            arr = new boolean[5];
            break;
        case 1:
            arr = new boolean[10];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**JSON Data:**

> {   "list": [
>       {
>         "type": 0,
>         "text": "Text 1"
>       },
>       {
>         "type": 1,
>         "question": "Text 2"
>       }   ] }

**Parser:**

```
ArrayList<MyList> getList(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyListsArray mLists = gson.fromJson(bufferString, MyListsArray.class);
    return mLists.list;
}
```

**Class to hold the list items:**

```
public class MyListsArray {
    public ArrayList<MyList> list;
}
```

> **Everything goes fine, I get proper values for type and text which are present in the JSON String. But the arr remains null.**

Comment: The JSON sample does not contain any boolean arrays, therefore the empty result

Comment: But isn't it supposed to go through the constructor and initiate the boolean array?

Comment: You cannot safely create a `boolean` primitive array reflexively. You need a wrapper. See: [Using GSON to parse a JSON array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421674/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-array)

Comment: Which int values do you get for type in the objects that are created?

Comment: @Pphoenix my sample json string has both 0,1 type

Comment: Your json does not contain the array of boolean (arr property), If you want to populate it then you need to write custom JsonDeserializer

Comment: @bhutto Yeah. But I thought this process will go through the Constructor and eventually create a boolean array. So, how to initiate data which is not present in the Json string?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Gson uses the properties not getter/setter and Gson instantiate the class object by invoking the default constructor

Comment: @bhutto One of my friend said: `If I declare the variable **type** as private, the Gson with try to find if there is a setter method for it and use it. So, in that setter method I can initialize other variables like the arr in my case.` Is that true? Because when I tried it didn't work.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc  GSON use ONLY fields(private,public,protected). Doc says : There are good arguments to support properties as well. We intend to enhance Gson in a latter version to support properties as an alternate mapping for indicating Json fields. For now, Gson is fields-based  see doc here https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-design-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  initiate data which is not present in the Json string as below write CustomDeserializer

```
class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<MyList>> {

    @Override
    public List<MyList> deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

       JsonArray jsonArray =    jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("list");

       List<MyList>  list=new ArrayList<>(30);
       Gson gson = new Gson();

       for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {

                MyList ob =  gson.fromJson(element,  MyList.class);
                switch (Integer.valueOf(ob.type)) {
                case 0:
                    ob.arr = new boolean[5];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ob.arr = new boolean[10];
                    break;
                }

               list.add(ob);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Finally parse it

```
 Type typeOf = new TypeToken   <List<MyList>>(){}.getType();
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(typeOf, new CustomDeserializer()).create();
 List<MyList> list = gson.fromJson(builder.toString(),typeOf);
```

Gson documentation says, if your class doesn't have an no-args constructor and you have not registered any InstanceCreater objects, then it will create an ObjectConstructor (which constructs your Object) with an UnsafeAllocator which uses Reflection to get the allocateInstance method of the class sun.misc.Unsafe to create your class' instance.

If you do have a no-args constructor, Gson will use an ObjectConstructor which uses that default Constructor by calling

```
yourClassType.getDeclaredConstructor(); // ie. empty, no-args
```

Answer (score 2):

GSon **never** calls a constructor of a MyList class in your code. That's why arr gets the default value. Which is *null*.