# Convert a Nested Json Array to Java Array Using Gson In Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I have a Json array like this

String carJson = "[{ \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }, { \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }]";

so far i have done this

```
Car cars = gson.fromJson(carJson,Car[].class);
```

and my car class is

```
  private static class Car {
            private String brand = null;
            private int doors = 0;

            public String getBrand() { return this.brand; }
            public void   setBrand(String brand){ this.brand = brand;}

            public int  getDoors() { return this.doors; }
            public void setDoors (int doors) { this.doors = doors; }
    }
```

But its not working.
How can I convert this string array to Java array? And how to retrieve the elements using the keys?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421674/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-array

Comment: This json is invalid. The internal arrays aren't correct, it's an `object` structure instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your source Json is incorrect.

The internal `arrays` should be changed to `objects`, because `arrays` aren't a `key` and `value` structure, and because these internal `objects` should be mapped to `Car` objects.

So change your `json` string like this:

```
String carJson = "[{ \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }, { \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }]";
```

Then these internal objects will be mapped to `Car` objects in Java, using this code:

```
Car[] cars = gson.fromJson(carJson, Car[].class);
```

Then to read the cars array data, you can use:

```
for(int i=0; i<cars.length; i++){
    Car c = cars[i];
    System.out.println("Car "+ i +" is : Brand= "+ c.getBrand() + "and doors = "+c.getDoors());
}
```

And this is how should be your `Car` class defined:

```
public class Car {
    private String brand;
    private int doors;

    //Constructors

    public String getBrand(){
       return this.brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String b){
       this.brand = b;
    }

    public String getDoors(){
       return this.doors;
    }

    public void setDoors(int n){
       this.doors= n;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write the class car???...and can you tell me how will i retrive the array elements??

Comment: Also in "Car cars = gson.fromJson(carJson,Car[].class);" its giving "Cast...car to class"

Answer (score 0):

Fix your json:

```
String carJson ="[{ \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }, { \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }]";
```

And then you can do:

```
Car cars[] = new Gson().fromJson(carJson, Car[].class);

class Car {
    private String brand;
    private int doors;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I m getting an error in "Car cars[] = new Gson().fromJson(carJson, Car[].class);" it says  cast..car to class