# Gson HTTP response object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson library for first time. I am making an HTTP request and pulling response (JSON response) and need to pull a specific result.

```
StringBuilder response;
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
    String line;
    response = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
    }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(response));
```

The response looks like this below, and I need to pull only `cardBackId`:

```
[{\"cardBackId\":\"0\",\"name\":\"Classic\",\"description\":\"The only card back you\u0027ll ever need.\",\"source\":\"startup\",\"sourceDescription\":\"Default\",\"enabled\":true,\"img\":\"http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/backs/original/Card_Back_Default.png\",\"imgAnimated\":\"http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/backs/animated/Card_Back_Default.gif\",\"sortCategory\":\"1\",\"sortOrder\":\"1\",\"locale\":\"enUS\"
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert a JSON string into an object?

Comment: gson.toJson(response) is pulling the full response. I only want to pull the "cardBackId".

Comment: StringBuilder resp;

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                String line;
                resp = new StringBuilder();

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    resp.append(line);
                }
            }

Comment: `toJson()` converts an object to a JSON string. `fromJson()` converts a JSON string to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) (which is a Java library for selecting parts of a JSON object) to extract just the part you need from the string.

Alternatively, you could write a class that only contains the field you want:

```
public class CardBackIdResponse {
    public int cardBackId;
}
```

And then use Gson to unmarshall the JSON into your object:

```
CardBackIdResponse[] cardBackIdResponses = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), CardBackIdResponse[].class);
System.out.println("cardBackId = " + cardBackIdResponses[0].cardBackId);
```

When unmarshalling an object from JSON, if Gson cannot find a field in the object to populate with a value from the JSON, it will just discard the value. That's the principle we could use here.

**Edit**: Altered answer above to handle JSON array as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421674/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-array).

Comment: More docs on how to use Gson: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: I receive error below when using your suggested solution.

Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Edited answer to handle that `response` is actually a JSON array.

Comment: I was able to resolve. 

            CardResponse[] list = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), CardResponse[].class);
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(list[1]));