# How to create java list from json using gson? Getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception, gson

In my Android project I'm trying to create a list of MyType using gson. For this I use the following code:

```
String result = "[{\"text\": \"lala\", \"created\": \"123456\"}, {\"text\": \"lele\", \"created\": \"123456\"}]";

class ReceivedMessage {
    String text;
    String created;
}

List<ReceivedMessage> receivedMessages = new Gson().fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<ReceivedMessage>>(){}.getType());

for (ReceivedMessage mess : receivedMessages) {
    Log.wtf("This is it", mess.created);
}
```

Unfortunately I get a nullpointerexception. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the class "outside" worked pretty well:

```
public class ReceivedMessage {
    String text;
    String created;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = "[{\"text\": \"lala\", \"created\": \"123456\"}, "
                    +"{\"text\": \"lele\", \"created\": \"123456\"}]";

    List<ReceivedMessage> receivedMessages = new Gson().fromJson(result,
                      new TypeToken<List<ReceivedMessage>>() {}.getType());

    for (ReceivedMessage mess : receivedMessages) {
        System.out.println("This is it " + mess.created);
    }

    ....
}
```

Note: Gson uses reflection and so it needs access to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ReceivedMessage>>() {}.getType();
List<ReceivedMessage> receivedMessages= new Gson().fromJson(result, listType);
```

[Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)