# Resetting Message Number for Inbox Style Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Edit: It won't allow me to accept my own answer for 2 days, but I figured it out. See my answer below if you have a similar problem

I'm working on stacking the push notifications from my app and displaying them using InboxStyle with a summary text. Currently, I'm displaying up to 3 notifications, followed by a "+ x more" message if necessary. To do so, I'm keeping track of then number of messages; however, I'm unsure how to reset the number of messages when the user clicks on the notification. For example, if the user gets 3 notifications, then clicks on the push notification to go into the app, I would like the next notification to be displayed as a single notification but it's currently being displayed "message a message b message c + 1 more." Is there a listener of some sort that I could use to reset message number to 0 when the user cancels the notification? Code below for reference:

```
 public class GCMPushReceiverService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMPushReceiverService";
private int objectTypeCode; //DLS
private String contentText;
private String objectKeyGUID; //DLG
private String alert;
private String sound;
private boolean vibrate;
private String contentTitle;
private String collapse_key;
private String tickerText;
private static int message_number = 0;
private static ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

private static final String MY_GROUP  = "my_group";

//with every new message
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data){
    this.objectTypeCode =  Integer.parseInt(data.getString("objectTypeCode"));
    this.contentText = data.getString("contentText");
    this.objectKeyGUID = data.getString("objectKeyGUID");
    this.alert = data.getString("alert");
    this.sound = data.getString("sound");
    this.vibrate = Boolean.parseBoolean(data.getString("vibrate"));
    this.contentTitle = data.getString("contentTitle");
    this.collapse_key = data.getString("collapse_key");
    this.tickerText = data.getString("ticker_Text");

    messages.add(message_number, contentTitle +": " + contentText);
    message_number++;

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    sendNotification();
}

private void sendNotification() {
    Intent intent;


   if (objectKeyGUID != null && !objectKeyGUID.equals("")) intent = deepLink();
   else  intent = new Intent(this, LogInPage.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    int requestCode = 0;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);




    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    noBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    noBuilder.setContentText(contentText);
    noBuilder.setTicker(tickerText);
    noBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    noBuilder.setSound(sound);
    noBuilder.setGroup(MY_GROUP);
    noBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon);
    noBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);



    //if we have more than one message, we want to display them in one notification, inbox style
    //if it's more than 3, display the first three and have a "+ x more" message
    //TODO: reset the message_number when we click the notification 
    if (message_number > 1) {
        noBuilder.setContentTitle(message_number + " messages");

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        for (int i = 0; i < message_number && i < 3; i++)
            inboxStyle.addLine(messages.get(i));
        if (message_number > 3)
            inboxStyle.setSummaryText("+ " + (message_number - 3) + " more");
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(message_number + " Notifications");
        //noBuilder.setContentTitle(message_number + " Notifications");
        noBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
    }

    else {
        noBuilder.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue by using a Singleton class-- I stored the ArrayList of messages as well as the message_number value in the singleton class. I called getMessageNumber and getMessages in onMessageRecieved, and then I set the new values again at the end of my sendNotification method. I then reset the values to 0 for message_number and null for the ArrayList respectively in my onResume listener of my main activity, so that whenever the app was opened the notifications were refreshed. I found [How to keep track of notifications to know when to show a summary notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273570/how-to-keep-track-of-notifications-to-know-when-to-show-a-summary-notification) to be helpful--- hopefully this post and that one will help anyone else with a similar problem