# Json deserialize object to list - is it real?

Tags: java, json, gson

Let's assume we have JSON object like this:

```
{
 "employees" : {
        "Mike" : 23,
        "Bill" : 42,
        "Jimmy" : 30
    }
}
```

And the next classes:

```
public class Employees {

    private List<Employee> employees;
}


public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Have we any ways to deserialize the json to Employees type object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)

Comment: Refer to this tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/
Also, the `employees` in your JSON has to be an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

List can be used to deserialize array of elements `[...]` but `{...}` is object. If you want you can consider using `Map` instead of `List`

```
class Data {
    Map<String,String> employees;
}

...
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> emp: data.employees.entrySet())
    System.out.println(emp.getKey()+" -> "+emp.getValue());
```

Output:

```
Mike -> 23
Bill -> 42
Jimmy -> 30
```

---

If you would like to parse your json using these classes

```
public class Employees {
    private List<Employee> employees;
}


public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Your data should look like:

```
{
    "employees" : [
        {"name":"Mike", "age": 23},
        {"name":"Bill", "age": 42},
        {"name":"Jimmy", "age": 30}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I know about correct json, but i hoped I can resolve this problem and link this json with that class. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jackson`'s `ObjectMapper` class to deserialize JSON like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349488/2413303