# Gson - putting and getting ArrayList of composite objects

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I have class `NameAndPostion` in which I am going to store name and position of users. And I have created `ArrayList` of objects of `NameAndPosition`.

```
ArrayList<NameAndPosition> LocSenders = new ArrayList<NameAndPosition>();
```

Now I have converted `LocSenders` into JSON string by using Gson library

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(LocSenders);
```

I did this conversion to save `LocSenders` in Shared Pref.
Now I want to retrieve all objects in 'LocSenders' which I have stored using Gson JSON conversion.

I want to do this work using Gson library.
I am not getting the Gsons method `gson.fromJson(json, classOfT)`. So how to do that properly?

**NameAndPostion.java**

```
public class NameAndPosition {

    private String name = "";
    private LatLng position = null;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(LatLng position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want object of NameAndPosition??

Comment: yes. I want to retrieve all stored objects into LocSenders ArraList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example of convert to JSON and from JSON using gson.

```
//Convert to JSON
System.out.println(gson.toJson(employee));

//Convert to java objects
System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{'id':1,'firstName':'Lokesh','lastName':'Gupta','roles':['ADMIN','MANAGER'],'birthDate':'17/06/2014'}"
                            , Employee.class));
```

Deserialize collection

```
List<Employee> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, Employee.class);
```

For generic Collection.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>() {
                    }.getType();
List<YourClass> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

you can also refere below link.

[Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)

Comment: How to store all objects again in ArrayList?

Comment: It is by default importing the class Type from java.lang.reflect.Type. And again editor prompting me for type casting? Which Type class I should import?

Comment: Thanks. Got the solution   
LocSenders = gson.fromJson(json, 
      new TypeToken<ArrayList<NameAndPosition>>(){}.getType());