# Android - save custom model ArrayList to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList and I need to convert it to a JSONarray:

This is how an Object in my `ArrayList<model>` looks like:

```
modelList.add(new model("String", 9.99 /*Double*/, null /*Date*/, R.drawable.drawable, R.color.color, 1 /*int*/, 0 /*int*/));
...
```

this is what I tried so far:

```
public void saveArrayListtoJSON(ArrayList<Model> modelList) {
        JSONArray myJSONArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("key", modelList);
            myJSONArray.put(obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this Gradle in your `build.gradle` `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`

and then

```
String str = new Gson().toJson(modelList);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this :

```
  public void saveArrayListtoJSON(ArrayList<Model> modelList) {
        JSONArray myJSONArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for(Model model : modelList){
            try {
                obj.put("key", model);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myJSONArray.put(obj);
        }
    }
```

Revert for any error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gson as well and just give the arraylist as parameter. But be careful all elements of your model need to be serializable if not use transient to remove object which is not serializable in your model

[Gson - putting and getting ArrayList of composite objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426062/gson-putting-and-getting-arraylist-of-composite-objects)

Take a look here too: [Deserialize a List<T> object with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Timo. Can you provide me an example on how to use Gson to save and retrieve the arrayList? the `List<Model> modelList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, Model.class);` does not work for me. I get `incompatible types`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type  or Model[] models = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray,Model[].class);

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below:

```
    public void saveArrayListtoJSON(ArrayList<Model> modelList) {
    JSONArray myJSONArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for (Model model:modelList) {
            array.put(model.getJson());
        }
        obj.put("key", array);
        myJSONArray.put(obj);
    }
}
```

I suppose that method getJson() is your method which return JSON object which present Model object

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to convert ArrayList to JSON array

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourArraylist);
```