# Android: How can I get Gson LinkedTreeMap values?

Tags: android, object, gson, android-json

I'm trying to simply get values from my Gson Object, so in my "city" Object:

[image: LinkedTreeMap Array]

I need to get the name "first" and the boolean value from "isSelected".

I just wrote a new class "KeyPairBoolData":

```
class KeyPairBoolData {
    int id;
    String name;
    boolean isSelected;

}
```

but I have no idea what should I write in the new class to get these values, here is how I'm trying to get it:

```
List<KeyPairBoolData> city = gson.fromJson(myListArray, listArray.getClass());
```

any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Method to deserialize generic collection:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>>() {
                    }.getType();
List<KeyPairBoolData> keyPairBoolDataList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Import : `import java.lang.reflect.Type;`

Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5554296/4848308