# Convert Json to List Java

Tags: java, json, gson, android

I have a JSON array like this :

```
    [
      {"_id": {"$oid":"57e9e4b1f36d281c4b330509"}, "user": "edmtdev" },
      {"_id": {"$oid":"57e9e4cec2ef164375c4c292"}, "user": "admin1234" },
      {"_id": {"$oid":"57ea1b0ac2ef164375c5ff1e"}, "username": "admin34" }
   ]
```

This is my `User.class`, used to store all data:

```
 public class User{
       private Id id;
       private String user;

       public Id getId() {
          return id;
       }

       public void setId(Id id) {
          this.id = id;
       }

       public String getUser() {
          return user;
       }

       public void setUser(String user) {
          this.user = user;
       }
    }
```

And my `Id.class`, used to store the ID:

```
public class Id {

   private String $oid;

   public String get$oid() {
     return $oid;
   }


   public void set$oid(String $oid) {
     this.$oid = $oid;
   }
}
```

I am using `GSON` in Java to get my users as a `List<User>`:

```
   List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   Type listType = new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType();
   users = gson.fromJson(s,listType);
```

The problem is, I get users with username but no ID, $oid is not registered. Can someone help me understanding what does not work in this piece of code ?

Comment: Are you using CouchDB ? I think GSON does not registed `_id` as a field, but I'm not sure at all. Try `debug` mode with a breakpoint to check if you receive the right object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must replace id in User class by:

```
private Id _id;
```

because your json is `_id`, not `id`. And your json string at the end is wrong, is `user`, not `username`

Comment: Work like a charm ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

```
@SerializedName("_id")
private Id id;
```

This is another approach.
You can use this above annotation also.