# GSON serialization plain array without name

Tags: android, json, gson

Code of UserRequest class, which contains the list of users.

```
public class UserRequest {
    private List<User> userList;

    public UserRequest() {
    }

    public UserRequest(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return this.userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

}
```

Code of User Class, which contains the id, first name and last name of the user.

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I am using the GSON library, and the issue that I'm having is that my json request when serializing from java objects to json is not formatted in the way I need it to be.

The format of current situation

```
{"userList":[{"id":"12341234", "firstName": "Joeri", "lastName": "Verlooy"}]}
```

The format that is desirable:

```
[{"id":"12341234", "firstName": "Joeri", "lastName": "Verlooy"}]
```

Is there a way that I can send the plain array of json object without any name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)

Comment: @LyubomyrShayDariv I'm having issues with serialization, not with deserialization

Comment: @JoeriVerlooy Not a problem: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type- and its overloads.

Comment: edited my answer again so you can make an json including a list without any name.

Comment: can you add the code you used to create that output? have you tried to use TypeToken or called toJSON directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse "custom" JSON using Gson library you need to use custom TypeAdapter where you'll be able to create list of Users object from unnamed array. [Here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/) you have example usage of TypeAdapter.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will look into the article.

Comment: I use custom type adapters in my project. [Here](https://github.com/ostojan/360toOne/blob/master/AndroidApp/app/src/main/java/com/ostojan/x360/model/GameTypeAdapter.java) and [here](https://github.com/ostojan/360toOne/blob/master/AndroidApp/app/src/main/java/com/ostojan/x360/model/RegionTypeAdapter.java) you can find my implementations.

Comment: I don't think that the OP has to re-invent the overkill wheel: the OP seems just to get the list from the request object and convert it to JSON representation.

Comment: I agree that my solution might be overkill but I think it's more robust and "elegant".

Comment: This solution worked like a charm, thanks! It might look like overkill but the fact that i can make a class that parses my data in an elegant way to the correct format is a big plus IMO.

Answer (score 2):

try to create a model for items (User) and then convert json to an java ArrayList. assume the json string is in `strJson`, then you can do it like below:

```
 ArrayList<User> lstItems = (new Gson()).fromJson(strJson, new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {}.getType());
```

you dont actually need a model for the list of users (UserRequest), cuz the list doesnt have any name.

if you want to convert an object to a json including a list without a name do like below :

```
 ArrayList<User> lstUser = new ArrayList<User>();
 lstUser.add(new User());
 (new Gson()).toJson(lstUser, new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {}.getType());
```

Comment: Isn't this for deserialization instead of serialization? I want to create the json from java objects, not the other way around.

Comment: if you want to serialize just do it with an arraylist of user model. then it will be changed into an array without name.

Comment: You're missing one thing in `toJson` to make it more precise and align with the `fromJson` example better.

Comment: what am i missing ?

Comment: @AmirZiarati Generic class instances (usually) cannot hold _declared_ generic class parameterization due to type erasure, thus simple `.toJson(object)` _can apply_ different serialization strategies to each list element.

Comment: i think you wont need to care about that when converting from object to string cuz i just tested different scenarios in this case and there was no problem.

Comment: @AmirZiarati Suppose I have special type adapter for `List<User>` (neither special `List` adapter, nor special `User` adapter). `.toJson(object)` will omit the special type adapter because of having not enough information regarding the _declared_ type for the given list. Compare these: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object- and https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type-

Comment: sounds true . thanks alot bro. i thin k i must add the type token in to json as well . yes ?

Comment: @AmirZiarati Yes, it would be merely better: by adding the type to the `toJson` method you make sure that your JSON read and write strategies use the same Gson read/write configuration in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i=0;i<userList.size();i++) {
    jsonArray.add(userList.get(i));
}
```

userList will be your list of users and
here jsonArray will have the desirable format

Comment: Did you check it? It cannot work: no [JsonArray overload](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#t2) can accept the OP's `User` class instance.