# only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

Tags: android, generics, gson, kotlin, data-class

I know a lot of similar questions here in StackOverflow, but nothing solved mine.

I have a generic data class:

```
  data class ServiceCall<out T>(val result: T?, val exception: String?, val pagination: String?, val stringResult: String?)
```

I am trying to use like this:

```
Gson().fromJson(json, ServiceCall<SurveyListModel>::class.java).result
```

IDE shows error: **only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal**

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't use generics with `class`, as easily observable here:

```
List<Int>::class.java
```

It gives you the same error. To use the generic typ in GSON deserialization, do what is suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5554296/8073652

**EDIT:**

In Kotlin it looks like this:

```
val type: Type = object : TypeToken<ServiceCall<SurveyListModel>>() {}.type 
Gson().fromJson<ServiceCall<SurveyListModel>>(json, type).result
```

Here's a small proof of concept, I've written:

```
 class Token : TypeToken<List<Int>>()
 val x: List<Int> = Gson().fromJson(Gson().toJson(arrayOf(1)), Token().type)
 println(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you see my data class? I have to pass result type.

Comment: cannot access '<init>' it is 'public /*package*/' in 'TypeToken'

Comment: ``class Token : TypeToken<ServiceCall<SurveyListModel>>();
    Gson().fromJson(json, Token().type)``

Comment: I used this with Gradle uses a TypeOf class to wrap this. It looks like
`project.extensions.getByType(TypeOf.typeOf(Token().type))`

Answer (score 3):

If someone looking for the answer in Kotlin and Jackson.

```
val response = ObjectMapper().convertValue(dataObject, object: TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>(){})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a list of the generic objects pass it like this

```
listOf<MyModel>()::class
```

the function will be like this

```
fun myFunction ( inputList: KClass<T>){}
```