# espresso ActivityTestRule for activity with generic type parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I have declared an activity like this

```
class QuestionnaireActivity<T : ProfileModel> : AppCompatActivity()
```

I want to write an espresso test so I'm writting ActivityTestRule like

```
@Rule @JvmField
val activityRule = object : ActivityTestRule<QuestionnaireActivity<ProfileModel.PersonalInfo>>(QuestionnaireActivity<ProfileModel.LifeStyleInfo>::class.java){
    override fun getActivityIntent(): Intent = QuestionnaireActivity.getQuestionnaireIntent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), 3, ProfileModel.LifeStyleInfo())
}
```

but the compiler complains that(its about the argument of ActivityTestRule)

```
only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal
```

It is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401789/6432826) that generics can't be used with *class*.

If I remove the generic type parameter the error becomes

```
 Type inference failed.
 Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Class<QuestionnaireActivity<*>> but Class<QuestionnaireActivity<ProfileModel.PersonalInfo>!>! was expected
```

what should I do?

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar to [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-unit-test-failing-when-using-generics-and-mockito/1866/2) the solution involves defining an inline function like this

```
inline fun <reified T: Activity> activityTestRuleWithIntent(intent: Intent) =  object : ActivityTestRule<T>(T::class.java){
    override fun getActivityIntent(): Intent = intent
}
```

then the rule becomes:

```
@Rule @JvmField
val rule = activityTestRuleWithIntent<QuestionnaireActivity<ProfileModel.LifeStyleInfo>>(QuestionnaireActivity.getQuestionnaireIntent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), 3, ProfileModel.LifeStyleInfo()))
```