# Kotlin How to mock generic class in unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock MongoCollection class in kotlin

```
class MyTest {

  val mockCollection: MongoCollection<Document> = mock(MongoCollection<Document>::class.java)

}
```

it given an error **only classes are allowed on the left side of a class literal**

on researching a bit I found this
[only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401104/only-classes-are-allowed-on-the-left-hand-side-of-a-class-literal)
I tried create a type for **MongoCollection** and then passing it to the mock but it gives an error as the mock is of **Type**.

I also tried casting the mock to Document as below

```
val mockCollection: MongoCollection<Document> = mock(MongoCollection::class.java) as MongoCollection<Document>
```

but that gives an **NullpointerException** exception during access of MongoCollection inside implementation of code.

I have tried both the

- Mockito kotlin library -https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2/mockito-kotlin/2.2.0
- Java mockito core - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13

and both of them have the same error?

I tired writing the same test in java and casting of generics work in it.

```
MongoCollection<Document> mockCollection = (MongoCollection<Document>) mock(MongoCollection.class);
```

Does anyone have any experience of mocking generic classes in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following example for you:

```
interface Mosi<T> {
    fun mos(): T
}
```

then all three code snippets below work for testing and test are passed:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {

    val mosi = Mockito.mock(Mosi::class.java)
    @Test
    fun test() {
        `when`(mosi.mos()).thenReturn("Mosi")
        assertEquals(mosi.mos(), "Mosi")
    }
}
```

```
class ExampleUnitTest {

    val mosi = Mockito.mock(Mosi::class.java) as Mosi<String>
    @Test
    fun test() {
        `when`(mosi.mos()).thenReturn("Mosi")
        assertEquals(mosi.mos(), "Mosi")
    }
}
```

```
class ExampleUnitTest {

    val mosi = mock<Mosi<String>> {
        on { mos() }
            .thenReturn("Mosi")
    }
    @Test
    fun test() {
        assertEquals(mosi.mos(), "Mosi")
    }
}
```

if you get `NPE` the problem is somewhere else, maybe providing more code can help!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Create an extension on Mockito like this:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> mock() = Mockito.mock(T::class.java)
```

### Usage

Use the extension function like this:

```
val mockCollection = mock<MongoCollection<Document>>()

val mockCollection: MongoCollection<Document> = mock() // I prefer this one
```

I always use this instead of the original `mock()` function since the java class can be inferred. Saves some typing.

### Off-topic

It's even great for mocking Lambdas!

```
val callback: () -> Unit = mock()

someClass.doSomething(callback)

verify(callback).invoke()
```