# How implement new `.getSerializable()` method to deserialize data into hashmap from saved instance bundle?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, deserialization

I was using `bundle.getSerializable("data") as HashMap<Int, Int>`

but after changing `sdkVersion` to `33` [`.getSerializable()` API is updated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#getSerializable(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)).

I am unable to implement it for `HashMap<Int, Int>`

I tried -

`savedInstanceState.getSerializable("answer", HashMap<Int, Int>::class.java)!!`

but it gives warning -

> Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

After some searching I found [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401789/13962262)

The respective answer(above cited) quote -

> You can't use generics with `class`

Now I am not getting the solution of this problem. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `HashMap::class.java` and cast it to `HashMap<Int, Int>`.

```kotlin
val map = HashMap<Int, Int>()
map[1] = 123

val bundle  = Bundle()
bundle.putSerializable("answer", map)

val serializedMap = bundle.getSerializable("answer", HashMap::class.java) as HashMap<Int, Int>
println(serializedMap[1])
```

Comment: Also works the same way for `ArrayList<>`, just put ArrayList.class as the third argument in the new `getSerializable` function and cast the result as `ArrayList<Whatever>`.