# mergin different ArrayList types to ArrayList Object

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I download a JSON file with following  format:

```
{
   "name": "enter_username",
   "longitude": "22.601952",
   "latitude": "40.674065",
   "type": "Big_Pothole"
}
```

(this is the actual file `http://zachtsou.webpages.auth.gr/FetchLocationData.php`).
And I store them in different `ArrayLists`.
For example :

```
private void getDBLocations(JSONArray j){
    dblocations = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    name = new ArrayList<>();
    types = new ArrayList<String>();
    full= new ArrayList<>();
    // Traversing through all the items in the Json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try{
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            // Adding types to array list
            names.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
            type.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_TYPE));
            longitude.add(json.getDouble(Config.TAG_LONGITUDE));
            latitude.add(json.getDouble(Config.TAG_LATITUDE));

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Combining Longitude and Latitude on ArrayList<LatLon>
        dblocations.add(new LatLng(latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i)));

    }
}
```

I would like to make one common `ArrayList` so to be able to transfer it to new activity(for example google maps activity) and print all the items with a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one class for Location data like below..

```
public class LocationData {

private String name;
private String longitude;
private String latitude;
private String type;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getLongitude() {
return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getLatitude() {
return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}


}
```

After that, parse your `JSONArray` response as below

```
private void getDBLocations(JSONArray j){
ArrayList<LocationData> locations = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

// Traversing through all the items in the Json array
for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
    try{
        //Getting json object
        JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

        LocationData location = new LocationData();            
        location.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
        location.setType(json.getString(Config.TAG_TYPE));
        location.setLongitude(json.getDouble(Config.TAG_LONGITUDE));
        location.setLatitude(json.getDouble(Config.TAG_LATITUDE));

        locations.add(location);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Now you have one common `ArrayList` of locations. You can use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - use a json library to parse a JSON String - example bellow.

You can have one Object - Activity. Add getters and setters.

```
public class Activity {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private LngLtd location;
}

public class LngLtd {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
}
```

Then you need convert JSON String to Java Object. You can use different libraries. This is example of gson.

You need this dependency.

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
```

And then convertion

```
 Gson gson=new Gson();
 Activity parsedActivity =gson.fromJson(jsonString, Activity.class);
```

If you have a collection (array) of activities, it goes the same way

```
Activity[] activities = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Activity[].class);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17300003/4587961

If you use another library, rather than gson, here is an example of Jackson.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{\n   \"name\": \"enter_username\",\n\"longitude\": \"22.601952\",\n\"latitude\": \"40.674065\",\n\"type\": \"Big_Pothole\"\n}";//Your JSON String;

//JSON from file to Object
Activity activity = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Activity.class);
```

https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Or if you really want, you can create loop through json objects, as you do in your code example, and create `Activity` object one by one, and put them into the result collection. This guy has answered here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48439517/4587961