# Get values of generic enum that implements an interface

Tags: java, generics, enums, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface GenericMethods {
  public String getString();
}
```

With this interface, I implemented this enum:

```
public enum SpecificEnum implements GenericMethods {
  A("NOT"), B("RELATED"), C("TEXT");

  SpecificEnum(String string) {
    this.string = string;
  }

  private String string;
  
  @Override
  public String getString() {
    return this.string;
  }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to call a function with the parameter `SpecificEnum.class` and be able to call the `values()` function on that parameter, as well as the interface methods on the returned array elements. Something like this:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (GenericMethods gm : getEnums(SpecificEnum.class)) {
      System.out.printf(gm.getString());
    }
  }

  public static T[]<T extends GenericMethods> getEnums(Class<T> enum1) {
    enum1.values();
  }
}
```

However, after searching a lot, I haven't come across a case using generics with enums that implement interfaces at the same time. I also thinkered a lot with the generic types but I can't find the right syntax to be able to call `values()` on a generic enum class. The main objective is to have multiple related enums be managed all in the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you may be looking for something like:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & GenericMethods> T[] getEnums(Class<T> enum1) {
    return enum1.getEnumConstants();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (GenericMethods gm : getEnums(SpecificEnum.class)) {
        System.out.println(gm.getString());
    }
}
```

Results:
(demo: https://ideone.com/v6on2p)

```
NOT
RELATED
TEXT
```

Changes:

- moved `<T extends GenericMethods>` before return type since only there generic method can declare its generic type.
- modified generic type to `<T extends Enum<T> & GenericMethods>` to force T to also be subtype of some Enum aside from implementing GenericMethods
- used `getEnumConstants()` instead of `values()` as we are using `Class`, not `enum` type.

Comment: Thank you, works precisely as expected. As a follow up question, there wouldn't be any way to store the generic class inside an unrelated enum attribute because of its generic type declaration limitations, correct?

Comment: @Phaellow Sorry but I am not sure what you mean by "store the generic class". For now I suspect you may be looking for a way to create `Class` which would represent for instance `List<Integer>` (since we can't create it via code like `List<Integer>.class` as it will not compile). If that is the case then maybe this will interest you: [Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554217) - specifically `Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>(){}.getType();`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I mean to have a certain enum and inside it a field with type `Class<T>`, like `private Class<T> clazz;`, where T is the generic we have been talking about. I'm pretty sure that type parameter definitions aren't allowed for enums, but there could be a way around this that I don't know about.

Comment: @Phaellow Then no, sorry but I also don't know any workaround for this. But just because I don't know solution doesn't mean there is none, so maybe consider asking separate question about it (just include in it explanation of purpose for which you need that mechanism to avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)).

Answer (score 2):

Call [`getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--) on the `Class` object. As the javadoc says:

> Returns the elements of this enum class or `null` if this Class object does not represent an enum type.

The signature of your method is wrong too. Here is how to write it:

```java
public static <T extends GenericMethods> T[] getEnums(Class<T> enumClass) {
    return enumClass.getEnumConstants();
}
```

Of course, it might return `null`, because there is no guarantee that the `Class` object is an enum class. E.g. with the following class, `getEnums(Foo.class)` returns `null`:

```java
public class Foo implements GenericMethods {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "Boo!!";
    }
}
```

To make sure that the `Class` is an enum class, change the method to:

```java
public static <T extends Enum<T> & GenericMethods> T[] getEnums(Class<T> enumClass) {
    return enumClass.getEnumConstants();
}
```

*Tests*

```java
getEnums(Foo.class); // fails to compile
```

```java
SpecificEnum[] enums = getEnums(SpecificEnum.class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enums));
```

*Output*

```
[A, B, C]
```