# Creating a JSON object in Java and accessing it in javascript/jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, struts2

I want to create a JSON object in java code and then pass it on to javascript/jquery for parsing(further processing).
I am using Struts 2 framework.

This has to be done at page load, not after a AJAX call.
How to access the JSON object (created in java) in javascript/jquery.

Also are any API's for creating JSON object for java object??

Comment: check http://www.json.org/java/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out the [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

To convert an Object to a JSON string is as simple as:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(myObject);
```

For your use case (Struts 2), a simple solution would be to place the `jsonString` property in your `Action`, then refer to it in the JSP page as follows:

```
<!-- this goes into your .jsp -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJsonObject = <s:property value="jsonString" default="[]" escape="false" />; 
</script>
```

Comment: And afterwards, you should mention methods of embedding that string in a template - usually done simply through an extra set of `<script>` tags defining a variable containing the JSON.

Comment: I added a quick method specifically for Struts 2.

Comment: @AndreiBârsan : 1 doubt, using this would convert the json object into string. So in javascript would i still be able to do something like jsonString.data1 , jsonString.data2.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal use the snippet above that I added :)

Comment: @JensenChing : Is there any way to write this Java object without using Gson lib, Actually i have told this can be acomplished using struts2 json pluggin. But I dont know how to do it.

Comment: It's quite possible, I use it all the time when doing AJAX requests. Check out: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/ for an introduction. Basically in your struts xml you extend from json-default instead of struts-default, then you return a result type of json. This is commonly used with ajax requests, I go the GSON route when it's normally page requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496494/library-to-encode-decode-from-json-to-java-util-map) for the question library.
As for consuming the json string in javascript you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
 jQuery.parseJSON( string );
```

Comment: the variable i want to use is a class variable of action class, It wouldnt be directly accesible in Javascript.