# parse Solr xml files to SolrInputDocument

Tags: java, solr, xml-parsing

If I have individual files in the expected Solr format (having just ONE doc per file):

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">GB18030TEST</field>
    <field name="name">Test with some GB18030 encoded characters</field>
    <field name="features">No accents here</field>
    <field name="features">ÕâÊÇÒ»¸ö¹¦ÄÜ</field>
    <field name="price">0</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Is not there a way to easily marshal that file into a SolrInputDocument? Do I have to do the parsing myself?

EDIT: I need it in java pojo cause I want to modify some fields before indexing it with SolrJ...

Comment: Who writes the individual xml files? You? Someone else?

Comment: Too bad! I was wondering because you could directly use java bean with  [solrj annotations](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done programmatically. I know you're looking for a Java solution, but I'd personally recommend groovy.

The following script processes XML files found in the current directory.

```
//
// Dependencies
// ============
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.solr', module='solr-solrj', version='3.5.0'),
])

//
// Main
// =====
SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/");

new File(".").eachFileMatch(~/.*\.xml/) { 

    it.withReader { reader ->
        def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(reader)

        xml.doc.each { 
            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

            it.field.each {
                doc.addField(it.@name.text(), it.text())
            }

            server.add(doc)
        }
    }

}

server.commit()
```

Comment: adds each one as a text document. interesting

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** In order to convert XML to POJO, please reference this previous SO Question - [Is there a library to convert Java POJOs to and from JSON and XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658936/is-there-a-library-to-convert-java-pojos-to-and-from-json-and-xml)

Since you already have your documents in the expected format, you can just use the post.jar or post.sh script file as shown in the [Solr Tutorial - Indexing Data](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Indexing+Data) that both accept xml files as input.

Also, there is a [toSolrInputDocument()](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#toSolrInputDocument%28org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument%29) method in the SolrJ ClientUtils library that may be useful for you. Granted you would need to marshal the files into the SolrDocument class in order to use the `toSolrInputDocument()` method.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can do this.

```
private void populateIndexFromXmlFile(String fileName) throws Exception {

    UpdateRequest update = new UpdateRequest();

    update.add(getSolrInputDocumentListFromXmlFile(fileName));

    update.process(server);

    server.commit();
}

private List<SolrInputDocument> getSolrInputDocumentListFromXmlFile(
        String fileName) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<SolrInputDocument> solrDocList = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();

    File fXmlFile = new File(fileName);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    NodeList docList = doc.getElementsByTagName("doc");

    for (int docIdx = 0; docIdx < docList.getLength(); docIdx++) {

        Node docNode = docList.item(docIdx);

        if (docNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            SolrInputDocument solrInputDoc = new SolrInputDocument();

            Element docElement = (Element) docNode;

            NodeList fieldsList = docElement.getChildNodes();

            for (int fieldIdx = 0; fieldIdx < fieldsList.getLength(); fieldIdx++) {

                Node fieldNode = fieldsList.item(fieldIdx);

                if (fieldNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element fieldElement = (Element) fieldNode;

                    String fieldName = fieldElement.getAttribute("name");
                    String fieldValue = fieldElement.getTextContent();

                    solrInputDoc.addField(fieldName, fieldValue);
                }

            }

            solrDocList.add(solrInputDoc);
        }
    }

    return solrDocList;

}
```