# Is there an easy way to parse SolrInputDocument xml back into object form in camel context?

Tags: solr, xml-parsing, apache-camel, solrj

I use org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils to convert an SolrInputDocument into a XML string and send to a queue. Now I need to manipulate that xml in a consumer, Ideally I want to have the xml convert back to SolrInputDocument, So I can add/drop couple fields with its methods. Is there an easy way to achieve that? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generally use something like [xstream/marshall](http://camel.apache.org/xstream.html) API for this...that said, the XML that is output from the ClientUtils.toXML() call doesn't work with this approach.

per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839331/parse-solr-xml-files-to-solrinputdocument)..."this is best done programmatically"

Comment: I ended up going other way to get what I need. But the post you attached here is really interesting. will look at that later. thx

Answer (score 0):

The other way of doing this is to parse your xml then convert it to java class. You can use SaxParser for this. See this link.

[XML parsing using SaxParser with complete code](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-with.html)

Comment: I know I can always do that in SAX, I would expect that solrj has sort of nice interface to solve this problem, 'cause I really just need to make small changes there.