# SolrJ with Maven

Tags: maven, solr, solrj

I am a newbie in Solr and maven and i want to make a small application that index all my database tables via SolrJ .
For that i looked up at this [tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) where they are using MAVEN .
I installed the librairies and jars (except maven) but i had this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor
```

I looked into the tutorial and i saw that for resolving this problem we need to add this to my maven configuration:

> org.slf4j
>               slf4j-simple
>               1.5.6

Is there anyway to do that without maven? 
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean you installed the libraries and jars **except** Maven? Are you using Maven or not?

Comment: An alternative to setting up a Maven build is to use Groovy. It also has the ability to pull down it's dependencies automatically using the Grape "Grab" annotations. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839331/parse-solr-xml-files-to-solrinputdocument/8888386#8888386

Comment: @MarkO'Connor no i'm not using maven

Comment: Maven is designed to download a project's dependencies. I would suggest installing it.

Comment: But is it necessary to install it to play this tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven is the suggested build technology for the [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj), because it automates the management of 3rd party dependencies. Without dependency management it's a royal pain to decipher these relationships ([Jar hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader)).

What I could suggest is to use ivy, which has a [command-line mode](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html).

First download the ivy jar

- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar

To retrieve the following Maven module and all it's dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
           <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
           <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
           <version>1.4.0</version>
           <type>jar</type>
           <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then run it as follows:

```
 java -jar ivy.jar \
      -dependency org.apache.solr solr-solrj 1.4.0 \
      -retrieve "lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" \
      -confs default
```

Retrieves into the lib directory:

```
lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
lib/wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
lib/slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar
lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar
lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
lib/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
lib/solr-solrj-1.4.0.jar
lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
```

## Update

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor
```

This is due to a missing httpcore.jar file. I found this out by browsing Maven Central:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor%22

The recommendation on using the "slf4j-simple" is to provide a logging implementation in case your application doesn't have one.

Finally... This demonstrates what I've tried to say. In the absence of a dependency management tool ([ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)) you're on your own in deciphering the 3rd party jar dependencies.

Comment: in another term: can i use solrj without installing maven? i can manage my jars by myself because i'm not used to work with maven

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi Solrj is a Java library. Of course you can manage the jars yourself. Problem is it's up to you figure out how Maven is managing the dependencies between jars. What I offered in my answer was a mechanism to do the jar download automatically (Saves time and keeps blood pressure low)

Comment: When i added the mentionned librairies to my lib folder and added it to my build path and i run a test example i had this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor

Comment: and in the tutorial they said if you get this error then you have to add this :If you see any exceptions saying NoClassDefFoundError, you will also need to include:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I've added all the librairies mentionned above but it's still not working? what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

Use maven. Even with it, it took me a fairly considerable amount of time to get the dependencies right. The tutorials were all a bit lacking. Below is my pom.xml with the relevant dependencies that I had maven bring in. Perhaps it will help you.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wow, why commons-logging needs to be added explicitly rather than discovering the dependency is beyond me.  But that solved the problem I had.  Thanks!

Comment: why do we need to add solr-core dependency doesn't it works only with solr-sorlj